# gitlab installation on top of kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, devops

What is the best way to deploy gitlab to kubernetes? 
Can I just use gitLab omnibus dockrise package? with it's internal postgreSql and redis? any problem with this approch? I prefer the empeded DB.

note: helm deployment deploy three pods: gitlab, postgreSql, and redis

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the omnibus distro to get you up and running the quickest. I have a "kubernetes by examples" repository that you can pull down and just `make install` (see the manifests directory for what is being kubectl apply'ed) at https://github.com/mateothegreat/k8-byexamples-gitlab.

This also deploys a service using NodePort's and your gitlab service will be available at http://gitlab/.

Comment: I see you are creating mySql DB, doesn't omnibus package include postgreSql DB? and mySql is not recommended?